# How do I get OSGi bundle state programatically as String?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

As far as I know, I can get a bundle state programatically by doing `bundle.getState()` and that method will return the state as an `int` which refers to `Bundle.ACTIVE` or `Bundle.INSTALLED` or `Bundle.RESOLVED` or etc depending on the bundle. For some reasons, I need to  get the state value as a `String`, like "ACTIVE", "INSTALLED", "RESOLVED", etc. How do I do that?

Comment: I am not aware of this in the OSGi codebase. It may be that you just have to write your own simple switch/case statement.

Comment: @pauli I'm currently doing just like that. but I want to, lets say, future-proofing my code just in case so that I wouldn't have to add or change any of those switch/case statements when there are changes or even additions on the OSGi states themselves even though there more likely would be no changes in them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do your own switch ... OSGi started before Java had enums.

Something like:

```java
    private static String toState(int state) {
        switch (state) {
        case Bundle.UNINSTALLED:
            return "UNINSTALLED";
        case Bundle.INSTALLED:
            return "INSTALLED";
        case Bundle.RESOLVED:
            return "RESOLVED";
        case Bundle.STARTING:
            return "STARTING";
        case Bundle.STOPPING:
            return "STOPPING";
        case Bundle.ACTIVE:
            return "ACTIVE";
        }
        return null;
    }
```